# VBA to get MATCH values within a cell separated by comma from other cell

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I am relatively new to VBA 
I am looking to create a MACRO to match values within a cell separated by comma from other cell and tell the result whether there exist a match or not.

Input :

```
   a                         b             
1 abc ,edr,edd,eee          abc
```

Output :

```
   a                         b              c             
1 abc ,edr,edd,eee          abc           Match
2 abc ,edr,edd,eee          eef          No Match
```

Code :

```
Function TRACK(pValue As String, pWorking As Range)
    Dim pValue As String
    Dim xResult As String
    pWorking() = Split(pWorking, ",")
    xResult = " "

    For Each pValue In pWorking
        If pWorking = pValue Then
        xResult =  “ Match”
    else
        xResult = “ No Match”
    Next

    ASSEMBLY = xResult
End Function
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include the error you're getting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After splitting pWorking into an array, you can use the worksheet's Match function to determine whether pValue is contained within.

```
Function TRACK(pValue As String, pWorking As String)

    Dim vals As Variant

    vals = Split(pWorking, ",")

    If IsError(Application.Match(pValue, vals, 0)) Then
        TRACK = "No Match"
    Else
        TRACK = "Match"
    End If

End Function
```

Be careful with 'smart quotes (e.g. `“ and ”`). They are not valid quotes in code.